# How to use NLTK dataset in Kaggle kernel?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, kaggle

How do I download nltk stopwords in online server Jupyter notebook? 
In the local host, we can easily type nltk.download and downloading starts
but in online Kaggle server notebook, nltk.download doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In kaggle kernel, the datasets are already pre-downloaded and packaged.

You can simply do:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopwords.words('english')
```

See https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/nltk-datasets?scriptVersionId=5266785

Answer (score 0):

Error Snippet:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary
[nltk_data]     failure in name resolution>
False
```

Sometimes when you dont have you kaggle account verified completly you might not be able to enable the option of internet on to download NLTK packages, so first complete the verification process then you have the internet option enable on the left side of the kaggle notebook under notebook options.